# How to detect and pause and resume other app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to developer such as iapplock.
is there the method to detect the app starting point and pause and resume it after input the pin code?

Comment: According to the iAppLock, it only works on the jailbroken devices. I never came across any app doing it in the normal devices.

Comment: Quick answer is not possible for non jailBroken devices

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iapplock-pro/id1072033000?mt=8 is this also for jailBroken devices. Thanks

Comment: The apps show fake description in iOS you can't access this .